# "foundation" command is not known outside nodeJS folder

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation

I had to install NodeJS and subsequently foundation CLI (V6) without admin rights through the Shell. 
Everything worked perfectly fine first, but once I closed the shell and reopened it, I couldn't execute the "foundation" command outside the folder where nodeJS resides. Inside the NodeJS Folder, for example "foundation -v", works perfectly though.

I think there could be a problem with the path variable, maybe I'll have to set it manually from the shell each time I want to run it? If so, how can I do it? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Normally your PATH should include the folder of the npm / yarn binary which resolves the global packages. Do you use npm or yarn?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, at least in my case, the easiest solution seems to be setting the PATH variable manually each time I open a new shell...

Here is the "template" for the command if u run into similar issues:

set PATH=D:\nodeJS\node-v10.16.0-win-x64;%PATH%